# Finding different phase shifts

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions, curves

> Find the two different phase shifts that translate the cosine curve onto the sine curve. Write an equation for both new cosine curves and each phase shift.

I am not sure about the answer. Thank you!
$y = \sin (x-\pi/2)$ and
$y = \sin( 2\pi x-\pi)$

[image]

Comment: Hint: Plug in $x=0$ to both of the results. Do you get the same answer as a cosine would give? Also, the problem is talking about **phase shifts**. In the latter, you have also changed the frequency, so I would interpret that as incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

To shift a function like $f(x)$ to the right for "n"unit, what you need to do is $f(x-n)$, and you don't need to multiply anything since it will either compress or stretch the curve.

Since the question asks you to shift the cosine curve to the sine curve, you can either shift it $\frac{3\pi}2$ to the left or $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to the right.

You are translating sine curve in your answer, but the question asks to translate the cosine curve.

Hope this is helpful.